# How to fix System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException when loading types from Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Activities

Tags: paas

Whenever we restart or deploy to our server, I get the following error message for as long as I can remember.

```
    2019-02-06T17:56:51  PID[9040] Warning     9428 17:56:51 WARN  Counter initialization. Loading types from assembly Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Activities, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null failed
Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException
Message: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at Sitecore.Cloud.ApplicationInsights.CounterLoader.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<LoadCounters>b__1(Assembly a)
```

I'm using Sitecore 9.0.2 (180604) on an Azure App Service. Our local DLL version matches what's on our upstream servers. The image below shows the DLL version:

[image: Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Activities.dll version]

How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Have you checked the mentioned assembly in your bin directory and the assembly's version? Is this an upgraded solution or a clean install of sitecore 9u2? Does it run on Azure AppService or an onpremise solution?

Comment: @ÁrvaiMihálythe question has been updated. Thanks!

Comment: @Marcel Looks like in `web.config` in Azure App Service requires a `6.0.0.0`, but probably you have deployed version `6.0.1`.

Comment: Thanks @ÁrvaiMihály. Would you kindly elaborate on how that can be found? I'm unable to locate such a reference in any .config files.

Comment: My last comment was intended to tag @TamásTárnok

Comment: @Marcel I would suggest to compare all assembliy versions with a default Sitecore bin folder. Maybe you deploy a wrong version of one of the assembly.

Comment: We ran a beyond compare and there were no differences with regards to any Sitecore DLLs

Answer (score 1):

It's seems to be a bug in "Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Activities.dll", since it's compiled with a reference to the assembly "Sitecore.Marketing.Automation.Activity", which seems not to be present in the Azure packages for 9.0.2. - I would report it as a bug to Sitecore if I was you.